# Проверить наличие ссылки на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно проверить наличие ссылки на странице, искал долго, везде решение только по id элемента. Нужно что бы при удалении или любом изменении ссылки вида `<a href="http://site.ru">Do not delete</a>` выскакивал алерт.

Логика типа:

```
var link = '<a href="http://site.ru">Do not delete</a>';
if (link not found) { alert('Error'); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так как один из вариантов:

```js
$(function() {
  var flag = false;
  setInterval(function() {
    if ($('a[href="http://site.ru"]:contains("Do not delete")').length == 0 && flag == false) {
      alert('измена');
      flag = true;
    }
  }, 1000);

  $('input:button').on('click', function() {
    $('a[href="http://site.ru"]:contains("Do not delete")').text('some text');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://site.ru">Do not delete</a>
<input type="button" value="Изменить">
```